# RE: Getting the Adafruit_I2C Import Changed Into Another GPIO Layout

Tags: python, linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I have some problems with the MotorBridgeCape. I have all my software and I found most of it at GitHub.com at github.com/Seeed-Studio/MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB and at their Wiki at seeedstudio.com/wiki/Motor_Bridge_Cape_v1.0.

Here is my issue. I connect my battery, two motors, and I run the .py file for DC Motors from their Wiki page. I get an error. The error reads as follows:
•Error accessing 0x4B: Check your I2C address

I checked online at their site. The seeedstudio.com site, in the forum section, stated that in 2014 there was an addressed answer. This answer was to update the firmware. I go into my BBB/BBG with the MotorBridgeCape attached and I download the .zip file and then unzip it.

The update to the firmware is as follows:

```
1.Connect cape to your BBG/BBB, download http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/ ... e_v1.0.zip to your BBG/BBB
2.unzip the file
3.Go to the directory Motor Bridge Cape V1.0 (cd Motor Bridge Cape V1.0)
4.upload firmware (make flash_firmware)
```

Once I unzip the .zip file, I get a "directory." The directory is listed as Motor Bridge Cape v1.0. I have no underscores in the file/directory.

So, it is not listed as Motor_Bridge_Cape_v1.0 and I cannot move to that file/directory. So, I used "\" to move to that directory.

So, I get to the directory stated and I use "make flash_Firmware". That gets me errors, too.

Here is the code for the MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB:

https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB/blob/master/BBG_MotorBridgeCape/MotorBridge.py

Please see:

```
from Adafruit_I2C import Adafruit_I2C 
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 
Reset = "P9_23" 
MotorBridge = Adafruit_I2C(0x4b) 
GPIO.setup(Reset, GPIO.OUT) 


ReadMode  = 0 
WriteMode = 1 
DeAddr    = 0X4B 
ConfigValid =  0x3a6fb67c 
DelayTime = 0.005
```

This software above uses the Adafruit_I2C. Is there a way to change Adafruit_I2C to another "import" of GPIOs that does not have a bug?

The I2C import from Adafruit has a bug in it. If I can change the I2C import to import other GPIOs, like GPIO_46 and so on, I should be able to use the MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB in my current code to make things go.

Please see:
    import MotorBridge
    import time

```
MotorName        = 1
ClockWise        = 1
CounterClockWise = 2
PwmDuty          = 90
Frequency        = 1000

if __name__=="__main__":
    motor = MotorBridge.MotorBridgeCape()
    motor.DCMotorInit(MotorName,Frequency)
    while True:
        motor.DCMotorMove(MotorName,ClockWise,PwmDuty)
        time.sleep(2)
        motor.DCMotorMove(MotorName,CounterClockWise,PwmDuty)
        time.sleep(2)
        print "hello"
        motor.DCMotorStop(MotorName)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Seth

P.S. Any recommendations would be very helpful.

Comment: recommendation is to go back to the MotorBridgeCape site and post to their support/forum etc. There you will get the specialists that can help you. (But will gladly be proven wrong by the S.O. community and upvote any helpful answers ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: I checked out the seedstudio.com site and they had a forum but there is little to no activity on it. I got with the people that mfg. the Cape for the BBB/BBG but I have yet to hear from them.

Comment: Was going to check out contents of the image zip file to see it is something I can understand, but the link `.../wiki/images` doesn't work. Can you update your Q with working links? I'll be out for a while, but will look at this again when time allows. Good luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Once I listen"  in the context of the phrase "Once I listen and unzip the .zip file". Can you use another word for listen? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Motor_Bridge_Cape_v1.0 is the Wiki for the software code for the DC Motors and battery.

Comment: https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB/issues/3 is the site for the "Issue" for the MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB from SeeedStudio.

Comment: sorry, I don't see a way that I can help of this. Sometimes adding a 2nd Q to the support forum with some appropriate begging can get someone who is knowledgeable about the problem to offer help. But I did notice the 2 red sections for bugs on `.../Issues/3` link seemed like straightforward advise, Did you try the recommended work-arounds? That's about all I can offer in the way of 2-nd-pair-of-eyes-help. Good Luck!

Comment: Also, given the number of python members here on S.O., that you haven't received any other advise or ideas makes me think that I am not the only one that is having trouble understanding your Q. I know there are a lot of steps to get to where you are in your problem, but work with someone who is really a techincal writer to simplify your Q and hopefully improve your chances of getting help with your problem. OK, that's really all I can offer ;-/ ... Good luck!!!

Comment: Thank you...I will get with someone and attempt a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the line

`MotorBridge = Adafruit_I2C(0x4b)`

to

`MotorBridge = Adafruit_I2C(0x4b,2)`

and it worked for me.  Also make sure you have python-smbus installed.  See [this webpage](http://guitar.ucsd.edu/beaglebone/index.php/Beaglebone_Green_Wireless#BBGW_MotorBridge_Cape_Setup) for more information.

Comment: Please view my updated answer below. It deals w/ smbus2 instead of Adafruit_GPIO.I2C. The Adafruit library has been deprecated and smbus2 can be used in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...

I checked out the BBG and the Motor Bridge Cape long enough. I did as you stated in the above answer. Thank you. It was that additional 2 in the sequence of the software. I also needed python smbus to run the software correctly.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

An update to this item is now available on github.com at https://github.com/silver2row/bbg/blob/master/MBC/MotorBridge.py.

Also, you can view the README at the beginning of the github repository for accessing smbus2, getting your smbus2 line 302 changed, and for some simple source to test your findings.

There are a lot of changes to set up on your MotorBridge.py file. Please view the differences and change them accordingly.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

the Motor Bridge Cape "needs" the Adafruit_GPIO.I2C library since the Adafruit_BBIO.I2C library is not existent right now. Also...this is old news since the Adafruit_GPIO.I2C library has been deprecated.

It is read only now. You can find that info. here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/blob/master/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py.

This is what I use now for the Motor Bridge Cape I2C functionality: https://github.com/kplindegaard/smbus2.

So, instead of using the set up of the old way listed above, use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# * Copyright (c) 2015 seeed technology inc.
# * Author      : Jiankai Li
# * Create Time:  Nov 2015
# * Change Log : Seth Dec. 2019 w/ help from #beagle at Freenode
# *              and Prabakar's book called, "BealgeBone by Example."
# * license: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt is the license for my contributions...
# * license from Mr. Li can be found here: https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB/blob/master/BBG_MotorBridgeCape/MotorBridge.py (MIT).

# FileName : MotorBridge.py
# by Jiankai.li

from smbus2 import SMBus
import time
import pathlib

# reset pin is P9.23, i.e. gpio1.17
reset_pin = pathlib.Path('/sys/class/gpio/gpio49/direction')
reset_pin.write_text('low')

bus = SMBus('/dev/i2c-2')

...
```

Motor Bridge Cape and the BeagleBoard.org family of boards!